# Exporting and importing between different database releases (Oracle)

Tags: database, oracle, import, export, windows-server-2003

I have two database servers:

1. Oracle database 12c on Windows server 2016
2. Oracle database 9i on Windows server 2003

And I want to import a schema from server number 1 to server number 2. 
I exported a dump file as usual:

```
expdp system@tnsname/password directory=directory_name schemas=schema_name dumpfile=dumpfile.dmp version=9.2
```

Then I tried to import it into server 2

```
imp system@tnsname/password fromuser=old_user touser=new_user file=dumpfile.dmp
```

But I got the error IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown.
I searched the error and it tells the file is corrupted. However, to ensure that the file is ok I re-imported it into the server 1 and it worked fine. Also, the character set and the nls_length_semantic are the same on the both databases.

So, what is the solution? Did I miss something?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Your posted code suggests you're exporting with Data Pump but importing with the old skool `imp` utility. Not sure whether it makes a difference but please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

General rule says:

- export data using *export utility* of the lower database version
- import data using *import utility* of the target database version

In your case, regarding that 9i is an old version where data pump didn't exist, your only option is to use the *original* EXP and IMP utilities, both of the 9i database version.

I have no idea whether 9i's EXP is capable of exporting data from 12c database version and I can't even try it (don't have that old database).

As far as I can remember, there was compatibility matrix somewhere on the Internet, publicly available. Now it is *hidden* under My Oracle Support so - if you can, check what it says. I did; if your 9i database is 9.0.1, you're out of luck. If it is higher, then use - as I said - EXP and IMP 9.2.0 version.